# JBoss Class cast exception while accessing EJB3

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, jndi, classcastexception

I am having a weird problem here with EJB3. Deployed and EJB3 and am trying to access the business method from the deployed instance.
I get the following error when the lookup is executed:

- UserAuthenticationRemote is the remote i/face
- UserAuthenticationBean is the Bean

Code (which fails):

```
UserAuthenticationRemote remoteInterface = (UserAuthenticationRemote) context.lookup("UserAuthenticationBean/remote");
```

Error log:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.naming.Reference cannot be cast to eds.enhancedqc.authentication.UserAuthenticationRemote 
            at        eds.enhancedqc.client.application.LoginDialog$3.doInBackground(LoginDialog.java:220)
            at org.jdesktop.swingworker.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)

    Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openide.loaders.DataObject"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-openide-dataobjectdnd; mask=1; class=org.openide.loaders.DataObject
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openide.loaders.DataObject"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-openide-dataobjectdnd; mask=1; class=org.openide.loaders.DataObject
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at org.jdesktop.swingworker.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

---

Please help!

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: IMHO, you should take some time to write in good english and to format the code, maybe people will then have a look. PS: the error is weird, the client code looks ok, but what is org.openide.loaders.DataObject, why do you have a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on this class?

Comment: I figured the problem. The error was due to use of JBoss 5.0.1 lib/jar files, whereas I am on 5.1.0.
I cleaned up the project dependencies and it worked.
---
Abt bad English, I wrote it in a hurry and never meant to trouble anyone who's reading it. Afterall IMHO we are here to solve problems and not to write essays in Queens English :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the jar file only. so remove all the jar file form you project and take the jar file from jboss-6.0.0.Final\client folder, which is your running server and put as class path then it will run fine

Answer (score 2):

import jbossall-client.jar and remove jboss-client.jar from your classpath